# Is it possible to get youtube iFrame api to work on iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the youtube iFrame API to work on iOS?

I can get around the iOS *autoplay* restriction by creating a native app and setting the appropriate flag on the UIWebView to enable autoplay, however, even if that is done, operations for setting the playback position (e.g., seek and loadVideoById) simply don't work. Not clear if anyone at Apple or Google is working on this or if there's a work around?

Comment: Sure. There are a number of examples of iOS applications that use the iframe API successfully—pretty much any iOS application that features inline YouTube playback. The best place for specific bug reports (as much detail as possible, please) is our issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)

Comment: Great! The specific problem I've run into (using the iFrame API to set the playback position on iOS) is documented in Issue 2921 at http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=2921 . The person who submitted that issue appears to have provided code snippet to reproduce the problem. Do you happen to know if this has been resolved or if there is a workaround? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! I added a comment to to issue 2921. On iOS (and only iOS), loadVideoById doesn't work if you use "object syntax." You must use "argument syntax" (but argument syntax doesn't support endSeconds like object syntax does).